# The Generalisation of $\lim _{x\to \:0}\:\frac{\left(e^x-1\right)}{x}=1$

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

$$\lim _{\:f\left(x\right)\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{f\left(x\right)}-1\right)}{x}\right)$$

Is this equal to one, or this bottom one

$$\lim _{\:f\left(x\right)\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{f\left(x\right)}-1\right)}{f\left(x\right)}\right)$$

I am pretty sure it is the second one, but my teacher wrote the first one
. As an example, I typed in these two to compare the values in symbolab, but it wouldn't show the answer

$$\lim _{x^3\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{x^3}-1\right)}{x}\right)$$

$$\lim _{x^3\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{x^3}-1\right)}{x^3}\right)$$

I used the expansion of e and got the first answer as zero and the second as $1$. Is it correct?

Comment: The second one, yes. But if $f(x)\approx x$ then also the first

Comment: The second one is correct.

Comment: Is anything mentioned about $f(x)$  ?

Comment: You can  write  $\lim_{f(x) \to 0} \left(\frac{e^{f(x)}-1}{x}\right)=\lim_{f(x) \to 0} \left(\frac{e^{f(x)}-1}{f(x)} \right) \cdot \lim_{f(x) \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Comment: @Why This was not actually a question asked, but I just wanted to know the general case

Comment: @Why thanks for your method, its pretty smart. I will make sure not to miss it next time

Comment: @CalvinKhor Could you give an example for that $f(x)\approx x$

Comment: @AdilMohammed Sure, $f(x)=x$. A less boring one: $f(x) = \sin(x)$ as $x\to 0$. (but then, there are many different ways for $\sin x\to 0$ without $x\to 0$, so the notation $\lim_{\sin(x)\to 0}$ should not be used)

Comment: Please avoid non-standard notation such as $\lim_{f(x)\to 0}$. What you seek here is handled using limit law for composition of functions: if $f(x) \to L$ as $x\to b$ and $g(x) \to b$ as $x\to a$ and $g(x) \neq b$ as $x\to a$ then $f(g(x)) \to L$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor is $\frac{Sinx}{x}$ an example? of $f(x)\approx x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially right, but also the second one requires caution because
$$\lim _{\:f\left(x\right)\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{f\left(x\right)}-1\right)}{f\left(x\right)}\right)$$
is not really a "proper" limit. What does $f(x) \to 0$ mean? You should not regard $f(x)$ as an indendent variable $y$, it may happen that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \ge r > 0$ in which case it is impossible that $f(x) \to 0$. And if you consider
$$\lim _{\:x \to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{f\left(x\right)}-1\right)}{f\left(x\right)}\right) ,$$
you have the problem that the quotient is not defined for $f(x) = 0$.

The first one is definitely false in general. Even if you would find a reasonable  interpretation of $f(x) \to 0$, it is not clear that $x \to 0$ as $f(x) \to 0$. You may consider

$$\lim _{\:x \to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{f\left(x\right)}-1\right)}{x}\right) , \tag{1}$$
but in general this limit will not exist. The minimal requirement is that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. So let us assume that  $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and that $f$ is *differentiable*. Then by L'Hospital's rule we may consider
$$\lim _{\:x \to \:0}\left(\frac{f'(x)e^{f(x)}}{1}\right) . \tag{2}$$
It this limit exists, then also the limit $(1)$ exists and equals the limit $(2)$. But you see that the limit $(2)$ exists iff $\lim _{\:x \to \:0}f'(x)$ exists. This is not necessarily true, and even if it exists, it may have *any* value.

Comment: Can we say that, If $\lim_{x\to\ a}f(x)=L$, then

 $$\lim_{f(x)\to\ a}f(f(x))=L$$
 am I correct? But my claim is not rigorous, I know

Comment: @lone_student It should be $\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=\lim_{y\to L}g(L)$.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for your answer.! Do you have the opportunity to give a little more detail?  I want to write this in my notebook ..

Comment: @lonestudent Well, it's only a comment, not an answer. This is all assuming $g$ is continuous at $L$. A hint on how to write an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof: choose $|x-a|$ small enough to ensure $|f(x)-L|$ is in turn small enough to make $|g(f(x))-g(L)|$ as small as you like.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you so much..I almost understood..  I just couldn't quite understand your second limit formula a little bit $....=\lim_{y\to L}g(L)$ I could not understand where the variable $y$ comes from..

Comment: @lonestudent My mistake, that should be $\lim_{y\to L}g(y)$, which if $g$ is continuous at $L$ is $g(L)$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks again..  I almost understood.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what to be cautious about, it took me a while to understand. I suggest numbering important points/specific cases so that future readers like me will get to know that you have finished explaining this point and you are going to a new example (suggestion made with good intentions). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly more practical to work with the $o()$ notation.

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}=1\iff e^x=1+x+o(x)$  in a neighbourhood of zero.

So as long as $f(x)\to 0$ we can rewrite

$\dfrac{e^{f(x)}-1}{g(x)}=\dfrac{1+f(x)+o(f(x))-1}{g(x)}=\dfrac{f(x)+o(f(x))}{g(x)}\sim \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

The problem is reduced to study the limit of $f/g$ in zero.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, shouldn't it be $e^x=1+x+o(x)$?

Comment: Corrected, thanks for noticing the typo.